# Взаимоисключающие свойства типа typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Есть ли возможность в ts указать, что у объекта может быть только одно из перечисленных свойств ("aaa", "bbb" или "ccc")?
Нашёл способ сделать подобное с помощью дополнительного свойства, но хотелось бы обойтись без него:

```
type TestType = {aaa: string, type: 'a'} | {bbb: string, type: 'b'};
```

--

Если просто написать

```
type TestType = {aaa: string} | {bbb: string};
```

То ts примет такойобъект как валидный

```
const test: TestType = {aaa: '123', bbb: '456'};
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы объект

```
const test: TestType
```

мог быть либо

```
{aaa: '123'}
```

либо

```
{bbb: '456'}
```

но точно не

```
{aaa: '123', bbb: '456'}
```

Comment: ты можешь просто убрать лишнее поле.

Comment: какое поле имеется ввиду?

Comment: _Нашёл способ сделать подобное с помощью дополнительного свойства, но хотелось бы обойтись без него_ - вот это дополнительное свойство о котором ты пишешь.

Comment: @Grundy и с чего оно лишнее? Оно нужно для решения обозначенного вопроса. Но данный вариант не удобен. А если это поле убрать, то задача вовсе не будет решена: TestType будет допускать оба свойства ('aaa' и 'bbb') одновременно.

Comment: Почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: @Grundy это не я так думаю, это typescript так себя ведёт

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130358/discussion-between-grundy-and-hlearn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type TestType = {
  aaa: string;
  bbb?: never;
} | {
  aaa?: never;
  bbb: string;
};
```

Comment: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbmgXigbwFBSgQwIC4pEAnASwDsBzAbhygCNmB+YyiANwlPoF8oAH0wMCeNlA7deDZo2JkqdLH3pYsnPKSjBCcRMkhR0GMcQDk8cwBomzYgFdKAEwgAzKhGd8gA) - чот не работает :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ну так `undefined` можно.